# How do I link a JavaScript Program in HTML, and Get It To Run?

Tags: javascript, html

Please be patient throughout this, I am VERY bad at coding both JavaScript and HTML, and this problem is probably trivial to anyone who knows anything.

For a school project, I have to create a website with a JavaScript, interactive feature. I'm planning on making a button that subsequently, when pressed, prompts the user many questions, such as "Do you have an account?", "Username?", and "Password". I believe my JavaScript is written correctly, but when I link it in my HTML, and when I press the button that is intended to start this prompting, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here are segments of both my HTML and JavaScript code that I am using.

**JavaScript**

```
function LogIn(){
var Account = prompt("Do you have an account?")

if (Account = "yes"){
    var Username = prompt("Username");
    if (Username = "MarkColley"){
        var Password = prompt("Password");
```

...

```
else{
    confirm("That keyword is not acceptable. Try 'yes' or 'no' instead.");
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="CurrentShows.html">Current Shows</a></li>
<li><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/man-and-woman/154/man-human-person-login-512.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"><button onclick="Login()">Sign Up/Log In</button></a></li>
<script type="text/javascript" src="LogInSignUp.js"></script>
</ul>
```

If it helps at all, here is an image of what the button/area that I am trying to get to work looks like.

[An image of my unworking, useless button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMF6.png)

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript tutorials. The difference between `=` and `==`/`===` is covered **really** early on.

Comment: Side notes on markup: You have an `</a>` that has no `<a>`, and be careful using `button`: If you put it in a form, the default value of `type` for `button` is `submit` (e.g., if you put it in a form and don't say `type="button"`, it will submit the form).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fiddle with a fixed version of your code, now it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3xpy5tq/

What didn't work:

1. You used **assignment** instead of **comparison** (= instead of ==).
2. You missed a **semicolon** and a couple **curly brackets**.
3. Your function LogIn was **misspelled** on the HTML (`Login` instead of `LogIn`; JavaScript is case-sensitive).

   ```
   function LogIn() {
      var Account = prompt("Do you have an account?");
      if (Account == "yes") {
          var Username = prompt("Username");
          if (Username == "MarkColley") {
              var Password = prompt("Password");
          } else {
              confirm("That keyword is not acceptable. Try 'yes' or 'no' instead.");
          }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      }
   }
   ```

A couple suggestions:

As mentioned in some comments, go through JavaScript and HTML tutorials. Also, use a code linter in your favourite text editor. I use Sublime Text with one of its many plugins. It will help you find your errors by yourself.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That solved every single one of my problems! Thank you so much - my life is saved!

Comment: You're welcome. Please take my advice on code linters into account too. You could also accept the answer, tehee.

Comment: Haha yeah I had another problem with my code (used if else, not else if), and I used a code linter to fix it. Thanks for the advice! As for the tutorials, I have done numerous HTML tutorials, a basic JavaScript one, but neither of them covered how to link the program.

Answer (score 0):

To make the function fire you are to go this way:

```
<a href="#!" onclick="LogIn()">Click</a>
```

And to check if a value is equal to another one, you are to use the equal signs:

```
if(value_one === value_two)....
```

Because if you use the single equal sign, you are actually assigning that value to a variable.

So if you go:

```
if (Account = "yes"){...
```

You are assigning to `Account` the value of `yes`.

Comment: I tried doing this, but now when I click the link it just links to a raw word file of the JavaScript, but it doesn't run it. I may not be following your instructions correctly.